# Python - Plot Node Hierarchy using iGraph

Tags: python, graph, igraph, hierarchy

I have a dataset with staff and their job roles, and each job role is assigned a code: 0 for top-management, 1 for middle-management, and 2 for general staff. I now want to plot these roles using a hierarchical graph, so that all code 0 staff are on the top, 1 in the middle, and 2 at the bottom. I've found the layout in iGraph to do this (see below), however don't know how to control which nodes appear where. Is there a parameter that I'm missing to control this? Any help would be appreciated.

CSV:
https://github.com/Laurie-Bamber/Enron_Corpus/blob/master/15Below_60Employees_1.csv

Role Codes:
https://github.com/Laurie-Bamber/Enron_Corpus/blob/master/Dict_role_code.csv

GML: 
https://github.com/Laurie-Bamber/Enron_Corpus/blob/master/15Below_60Employees_1.gml

P.S. edges refer to emails between staff, not measures of hierarchy.

[image]

```
Code:
G = Graph.Read_GML('Test.gml')
visual_style['layout'] = G.layout_reingold_tilford()
plot(G, **visual_style)
```

Comment: can you add the data? or some data at least?

Comment: Sure, I'll upload it to my git.

Comment: Okay. Have you tried `root` arguments?

Comment: Links above the picture, cheers.

Comment: Not yet, I saw it however thought that the function would only allow for defining one node, not all. Can all be defined using this function?

Comment: Do you only care about which height a node is at based on the role codes?  Or do you also care about the horizontal placement?

Comment: The graph would show levels by hierarchy, so horizontal placement is not an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am proposing a solution with a slight modification to what you asked for. If you plot the levels vertically and the people at a role level horizontally, there are many people at one level so the labels run into each other. Instead, I am plotting the role levels horizontally and the individuals at a level are spread out vertically, leaving plenty of room to see the labels.

I do not think that there is a pre-built layout function that does what you are asking. However, it is not very hard to make your own layout. The essential part of doing that is to assign x-y coordinates where you want the nodes to be plotted. After that, you can just use the `Layout` function to convert the coordinates into a layout object.

My scheme for assigning x-y coordinates will be that the x coordinate will be the role level ( 1,2, or 3). I will just assign y-coordinates by making each node at a role level one higher than the previous node at that level. I use a small dictionary to keep track of what height comes next for each of the levels.

I will use the file names of the files that you provided and will assume that these files are in the current working directory.

```
import csv
from igraph import *

## Load graph
G = Graph.Read_GML('15Below_60Employees_1.gml')

## Load role levels
reader = csv.reader(open('Dict_role_code.csv'))
dx = dict(reader)

## Create a layout
height = { '1':0, '2':0, '3':0 }
COORD = []
for L in G.vs['label']:
    height[dx[L]] = height[dx[L]] + 1
    COORD.append((float(dx[L]), height[dx[L]]))
LO = Layout(COORD)

## Create the style
visual_style = {}
visual_style['vertex_size'] = 8
visual_style['vertex_frame_color'] = 'orange'
visual_style['layout'] = LO
visual_style['margin'] = 60
visual_style['edge_color'] = '#00000044'

plot(G, **visual_style)
```

[image: Enron]

I think that this provides you with a good starting place. You can tweak the placement from here.

Comment: Very very interesting what you've been able to achieve. Thanks for dedicating your time to this, it will come in very useful. I'll also investigate the possibility of defining my own layout as you have discussed. Thanks again.